# How to get android TV Application icon/banner which Is not installed on device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv

I Would like to show apps banners in my app which are not installed in my android TV. Is it possible to find a source where we can get app banner? I found only a method how to find icon but I need android TV banner

for example: I have application package so I can build an url, can I find an app banner with that?

[Downloading just the icon of an application from Google Play (Market)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058221/downloading-just-the-icon-of-an-application-from-google-play-market)
like here but banner(Android TV application icon)

[App Banner/icon screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YsVi.jpg)